# How do I send the text through the HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap, fxml

How do I pass the "toEncrypt" text through the hashmap and have it show on the "encrypted" label? It's been bothering me for a short while. I can only get what the user wants to be encrypted show on the label without being encrypted.

```
@FXML
Button encrypt;
@FXML
Label encrypted;
@FXML
TextField toEncrypt;

@FXML
private void encryptButton(ActionEvent event) {
encrypted.setText(toEncrypt.getText());
}

@FXML
private void secretMessage (ActionEvent event) {

    HashMap<String,String> secret = new HashMap<String, String>();


    //*****UPPER CASE LETTERS*****
    secret.put("A","9");
    secret.put("B","J");
    secret.put("C","Q");
    secret.put("D","1");
    secret.put("E","T");
    secret.put("F","B");
    secret.put("G","Z");
    secret.put("H","R");
    secret.put("I","t");
    secret.put("J","m");
    secret.put("K","q");
    secret.put("L","p");
    secret.put("M","o");
    secret.put("N","3");
    secret.put("O","v");
    secret.put("P","y");
    secret.put("Q","X");
    secret.put("R","z");
    secret.put("S","l");
    secret.put("T","S");
    secret.put("U","5");
    secret.put("V","w");
    secret.put("W","C");
    secret.put("X","K");
    secret.put("Y","8");
    secret.put("Z","n");
   //**********************


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: 'Send text through a HashMap' is meaningless. Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

It would be good to see what you've already attempted; so instead of just providing a full, working answer to the question, I'm just going to point out a few concepts which should get you going.

For the 'pass through the `HashMap`' step, you can iterate over the `char`s in a `String` like so:

```
final String toEncryptString = toEncrypt.getText();
final char[] encrypted = new char[toEncryptString.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < toEncryptString.length(); i++) {
    final char c = toEncryptString.charAt(i);
    final char e;
    // TODO - Set 'e' from getting the value from the HashMap
    encrypted[i] = e;
}
return new String(encrypted);
```

I'd assume you're setting this somewhere, but you're not setting the `encrypt` `Button`'s logic in the code you've shared.  `Button` has an `setOnAction` which you should be able to utilise here with something like:

```
encrypt.setOnAction(this::encryptButton);
```

You just need to find somewhere to set this which will *always* be run before you try to use the `Button`.

Finally, it would be remiss of me to not mention that having the `HashMap` constructed as part of the method seems odd (it will have to do so every time you try to encrypt something).  Having this set as a field (or similar - `static` field, hidden in utility class, with access via `static char getEncrypted(final char given) { return map.get(given); }`) would be more performant (although make sure you're handling potential `null`s in whatever solution you go with.

Hopefully that'll get you started.